# mdadm Boot Error, incrementally starting raid array Ubuntu SErver 14.04

Tags: raid, boot, mdadm

i build a small Server with Ubuntu 14.04 for Samba,
I has one SSD Drive (the ubuntu installation is on it)
and 2 3TB SATA Disk,
the sata disk are combined to a Raid 1 with mdadm.

Now sometimes (no everytime, i think it's maybe related to a dirty shutdown)
the system hangs at the boot process:

```
incrementally starting raid arrays
mdadm: Create user root not found 
mdadm: create group disk not found 
incrementally started raid arrays
```

these 4 lines keep repeating.
It's really strange cause the boot volume (the ssd) isn't configured as raid and this should not affect it?

Important edit: if i press ctrl + alt + del , the server reboots and starts up normaly,
if i look at the raid dev `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`
after the boot, everything looks good.

I'm not a linux pro and didn't find anything on the internet related to these errors, so now i'M a littel stuck, maybe somebody has a clue what the problem could be or some advanced troubleshooting advises (log files etc)?

thanks for reading
regards
Stefan

Comment: I had the same problem and after searching I found out that [this solution](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/33851#comment106076) worked for me. I just had to rename all `/dev/md/*` devices to `/dev/md*` devices in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and run `update-initramfs -u` to update the initramfs.

Answer (score 3):

Had this as well. In my environment: 2x SAS HDDs configured as raid10.

The problem was that `mpt2sas.ko` was not loaded, and thus `mdadm` couldn't see any disk. This in turn was caused by a packaging error:  when apt was removing unneeded wlan packages like crda, it also auto-removed the `linux-image-extra-$VERSION` package, which actually owns `mpt2sas.ko`.

To ensure, that the module gets loaded before the raid modules, I also did a

```
echo mpt2sas >>/etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Comment: This, along with Mitar's comment, above, about renaming `/dev/md/*`

Answer (score 3):

On my machine (Ubuntu trusty) this was caused by having a newer (xenial 4.4.0 -series) kernel installed under /boot and being used by default.

I solved this issue by booting an older kernel version and then running:

```
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
```

Answer (score 2):

finally "fixed" the error.
Short Version: The Transcend SSD (TS128GSSD25S-M) in combination with the  ASRock B85M Pro4 Mainboard caused the Error.
After Cloneing the System with clonezilla to a Samsung 840 Evo i booted now 30 times without problems.

in deep Problem report:
But why is mdadm showing up with totaly unrelated raid Array Problems? :
Well while creating the Raid Array (or maybe by default? i dont know exactly) mdadm put's a raid initialization script into the initramfs.
This scrip check if the rootfs is mounted, if the rootfs (on my SSD) isn't mounted it jumps to function mountroot_fail

```
message "Incrementally starting RAID arrays..."
if mdadm --incremental --run --scan; then
message "Incrementally started RAID arrays."
return 0
```

This leads to the confusing output. After Removing those scripts from initramfs i bumped into the real Problem:

Gave up wiating for root device. Common problems:

- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

  - check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

  ```
  ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
  BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash)
  Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
  (initramfs)
  ```

As the error isn't persistent i thought to give a different SSD a try, and BAM working.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution were missing "dm-mod", "dm-snapshot" and "dm-mirror" entries in /etc/initramfs-tools/modules. I took me quite some time to fight this issue as the error messages were talking about "mdadm" and raid - so how should one guess that lvm is the issue.

My setup:
`sda -> sda1 (0xfd linux raid autodetect, 500MB), sda2 (0xfd linux raid autodetect, 250G)`
same for sdb

- `sda1 + sdb1 --> /dev/md0 (mdadm) "/boot"`
- `sda2 + sdb2 --> /dev/md1 (mdadm) --> lvm volume for "swap" and "/"`

I didn't put "/boot" into the LVM to avoid hazzle with grub/lvm in the first place. But it looks like I just have fallen into another tarpit of grub/lvm/raid :(

I guess the issue was that grub properly mounted the initramfs and then it couldn't mount `/` (because of missing lvm modules) it tried to initialize some raid devices.

The `incrementally starting raid arrays` is somewhat misleading as it can be any missing module which inhibits `/` from getting mounted. Also see above post about missing `mpt2sas` module.

Additionally I tought the `dm_` modules were not necessary as they are for dmraid - which is wrong: They are also necessary for LVM. In my situation I did a switch from dmraid back to the good ol' mdadm because dmraid (fakeraid) caused problems (A directory just disappeared).

And last but not least I wondered that I can add `dm-mod`, `dm-snapshot and`dm-mirror`to`/etc/modules`and`/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`altough there are not really and`.ko` files by that name. Must be some kind of module aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The case for me was that I was using a 3.x kernel and upgraded to 4.4.x.  Booting the 3.x kernel fixed it and I've since removed the 4.4, there is definitely something incompatible or a problem with the initramfs that comes with it.